# How to add StackNavigator to a class which already has an export?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo, stack-navigator

I have a React Native app built with Expo. I'm using `createAppContainer` from `react navigation` to implement a Bottom Tab Navigator. Now, I want to add a Stack Navigator to navigate between categories in one of those tab.

I tried looking for solutions and different ways to use StackNavigator but none of them fix my problem.

this is my App.js

```
class Home extends React.Component {

}
class Female extends React.Component {

}
class Male extends React.Component {
   /* BUTTONS TO NAVIGATE TO OTHER SCREENS USING STACK NAVIGTOR */
}
class Saved extends React.Component {

}

const BottomTabMaterial = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },
    Female: {
      screen: Female
    },
    Male: {
      screen: Male
    },
    Saved: {
      screen: Saved
    }
  }
});

const CategoriesStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  CatA: {
    screen: CatA,
  },
  CatB: {
    screen: CatB,
  },
})

export default createAppContainer(BottomTabMaterial);
```

The problem I'm facing is that, how do I `export default CategoriesStackNavigator` when in the App.js already has an export???

Comment: You can't have multiple default exports. Instead use named export like this `export const CategoriesStackNavigator = ...`. Import it as `import { CategoriesStackNavigator } from 'App.js'`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: is there any other way to move between screens other than StackNavigator?